# Listview Highlighted onclick instead of item

Tags: java, android, listview, onclicklistener

I am trying to highlight an individual item in list view that was split from the string however the whole Listview is highlighted instead of the item.

Please help.

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        Local.Set(getApplicationContext(), "TicketHolders", result);            
        String[] RowData = result.toString().split("\\;");
        List<String> TicketholdersArray = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int x=0;x<RowData.length;x++){
            TicketholdersArray.add(RowData[x].toString());
        }

        // below creates and styles listview
        ListView listView1 = (ListView)       findViewById(R.id.your_list_view_id);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(GuestlistActivity.this,R.layout.liststyle, TicketholdersArray);
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ArrayAdapter, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I highly recommend you read [this tutorial by Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html). If gives you a great rundown of how Lists in Android work.

Comment: Do you want try `onScrollChangeListener`? Then i can suggest you solution.

Answer (score 0):

for working on the particular view in the listview item row you have to work with you adapter on get view() method fetch the view and set the listner color etc... whatever you need

Comment: Could you elaborate. Im relatively new to android

Comment: on the view you are changing the entire row color of the listview item. if you want custom listview and each row item will apear as you define in your xml file liststyle.xml and now if you want to fire event and access the view from each row you have to make a another adapter class which extends the array adapter and override the getview method and perfom than make a newly created class adapter and pass it to listview.. look at this example : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

To hold the color of listview item when you press it, include the following line in your listview layout:

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_key"
```

Then define bg_key.xml in drawable folder like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Finally, include this in your ListView onClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long arg3) {
        view.setSelected(true);
        ... //Anything
    }
});
```

This way, only one item will be color-selected at any time. You can define your color values in res/values/colors.xml with something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="pressed_color">#4d90fe</color>
    <color name="default_color">#ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Hope this helps you out

Comment: Tried this. its changing the color of the whole list instead of item

Answer (score 0):

listview has a property to show the selected item

add this code to your listView item_layout in xml

```
 android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

and this is your selector code. create a drawable selector file

```
 <!-- <item android:drawable="@color/android:transparent"  android:state_selected="true" /> -->
<item android:drawable="@color/list_bg" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/list_bg" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/transparent"/>
```

Comment: The problem is not in the xml. when pressed the color does change but the whole list changes instead of the item in the list

Comment: you mean to say that background of all listitems changes

Comment: read this answer again I have edited the code. It will work for you

Comment: Once again the whole list is changing and not the item. . I realy dont see how this can be a xml issue... Android is looking at the whole list when pressed and not an item.

Comment: hey please comment your list item click listener method and then run this code.